# Why this jquery function not executing?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input id="Edit" name="Edit" value="Edit Record" type="button" onclick="$.get('fetchvalues.php', function(){myCallBack(ReadCookie('UpdateRecordID'));});" />
```

The ReadCookie function is of another JQuery script.

I want to pass the cookie value to the .php file.

---

This how I modified:

```
<td align="left">
    <input id="Edit" name="Edit" value="Edit Record" type="button" onclick="$.get('fetchvalues.php', ReadCookie('UpdateRecordID'), myCallBack);" />
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#edit").click(function(){
       $.get('fetchvalues.php', function(){
       myCallBack(ReadCookie('UpdateRecordID'));
       });
   });
});
</script>
```

In the file: fetchvalues.php, I have written an echo statement to check whether AJAX call reaches there or not. But it is not calling that file. What's wrong?

Comment: What does happen? What errors are reported? What makes you think it isn't working? Why are you reading a cookie using JS and including it in the query string instead of just letting the PHP program read the cookie itself?

Comment: Nothing. It just stays on the same page.

Comment: Of course it stays on the same page. It's a `type='button'` so it isn't going to submit a form, it's jQuery's `$.get` function, so that makes an HTTP request in the background. You haven't provided a callback function, so nothing is going to happen on the page when the response comes back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't say from what you have just written.

I Would be interested to see more on: myCallBack, fetchvalues.php and ReadCookie

Certainly, start by making the JavaScript unobtrusive, and moving the click binding to the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        $.get('fetchvalues.php', function(){
            myCallBack(ReadCookie('UpdateRecordID'));
        });
    });
});
```

Another problem. If you're wanting to pass data, then data is the second parameter on the get function. See the documentation here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype

So, your function might be something like:

```
        $.get('fetchvalues.php', ReadCookie('UpdateRecordID'), myCallBack);
```

(p.s. check out the following for the click binding: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click)

Comment: How to execute the above code? I want it to be execute on the click of a button.

Comment: Suggest you read up on late binding. This line above helps you. $("#edit").click(function(){

Comment: Check out the get link on the post. jQuery.get( url, [data], [callback], [type] )